# AppSync Graphql query to javascript

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

So I'm trying to run this query in javascript but I never seem to get the right response.

```
query MyQuery {
  listUsers(filter: {email: {eq: "david@gmail.com"}}, limit: 1) {
    items {
      createdAt
      email
      gender
      id
      password
      profile
      updatedAt
      username
    }
  }
}
```

So this is my query in the online editor in aws appsync.
And this is my query in javascript.

```
async function findUser(login_email) {
    console.log("login email: " + login_email)
    const user = await client.graphql({
      query: listUsers,
      filter: {email: {eq: login_email}},
      limit: 1,
    });
    console.log("all users: " + JSON.stringify(user));
  }
```

But it seems to be ignoring my filter because i always get all the users back instead of the ones with the email I put in.
I look forward to hearing everyones ideas.

#### EDIT

This is my query definition pulled with aws codegen

```
export const listUsers = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListUsers(
    $filter: ModelUserFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listUsers(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        email
        username
        gender
        password
        profile
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        __typename
      }
      nextToken
      __typename
    }
  }
`;
```